# Azure Search service gives error "Expected a JSON object, array or literal" on spatial query

Tags: azure, geospatial, azure-cognitive-search, spatial-query

I am trying to use Azure Search Service for querying data based on spatial data.
I want to filter data based on geography. The query tried out in search explorer is `search=*&$filter=geo.distance(geolocation, geography'POINT(9.2869001 47.3532887)') le 50`

Type defined for geolocation field is Ed.GeographyPoint and attributes set are filterable and retrievable

But i am not getting results, instead getting message "Expected a JSON object, array or literal" in the result window.
What is wrong with the query is here. 
I am using Standard plan for Azure and API version used is API version: 2016-09-01

Comment: Before someone says "Read the docs", the example in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/odata-expression-syntax-for-azure-search#filter-examples) is: `$filter=geo.distance(location, geography'POINT(-122.131577 47.678581)') le 10` which is basically identical :D

Comment: if the $ is removed, then the entire data is coming as result. no filtering is happening.

Comment: Yeah the $ is mandatory. An OData filter is always $filter.

Answer (score 0):

Does your geolocation field has format similar to below?

```
"location": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -121.355, 47.71 ], "crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "EPSG:4326" } } }
```

Comment: I tried the query in the search explorer in Azure portal.

Comment: Is your `geolocation` field type of `Edm.GeographyPoint`? What attributes it has?

Comment: Type is Ed.GeographyPoint and attributes set are filterable and retrievable